# PHP Session is running but no value is set in $_SESSION

Tags: php, session

In the login form of one of my PHP project. After all validation I set `$_SESSION['username'] = $username` (where `$username` value is coming from `db_username` of that user and when I write `echo $username;` it prints the correct value).

Suppose `$username` is "Admin" so `$_SESSION['username'] = 'Admin'`.

After successfully login, the page reloads automatically, and here the issue arise. As I'm already logged in, it must show **My Profile** menu instead of **Login** menu, but it shows **Login** menu. So I use `echo $_SESSION['username']` which prints blank value, while it should print "Admin".

This works fine in my local server (XAMPP, PHP version: 7.0.9), but the problem occurs when I upload those code in live server (PHP version: 5.6.30).

PHP Session is running. As I use the following code to check:

```
if( !session_start() ) {
    session_start();
} else {
    echo 'Session is started';
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: At least don't call `session_start()` twice, there's no point. Check the cookies you're given from the server.

Comment: post you html and php code to identify any problem in script or just have server issue

Comment: please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45626938/why-i-am-unable-to-get-session-values-on-the-other-page/45627027#45627027 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422816/php-session-variables-not-being-passed-to-the-next-page

Comment: `if (!session_start()) session_start();` I lol'd.

Comment: Please update the question with how you are inserting data into session.

Comment: You should also put your `session_start()` in the very top of the first called script.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are running PHP version greater thatn 5.4, use the `session_status` function like this:

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
```

`session_status` returns following values based on the status of session.

> PHP_SESSION_DISABLED if sessions are disabled.
>
> PHP_SESSION_NONE if sessions are enabled, but none exists.
>
> PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE if sessions are enabled, and one exists.

Comment: Is there any security risk to check if session is already started? I am asking because I never check.

Comment: @RajendranNadar No.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem.

Replace this with

```
if( !session_start() ) {
    session_start();
} else {
    echo 'Session is started';
}`
```

This code

```
session_start();
```

There is no need to check if session is started. Php will display an error if you start session 2 times in a same page. So no need to check if it is started.